# AJAX call is not performed when trying to sort by a column in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting, jqgrid

I have the following jqgrid:

```
        $('#tabla-disponibles-zonas').jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("DisponibleZonas")?' + getReportParameters(),
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Type', 'Zona', 'Tienda', 'Inventariado ($)', 'Abiertos ($)', 'Abiertos (un.)', 'Abiertos (%)', 'No encontrados ($)', 'No encontrados (un.)', 'No encontrados (%)'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Type', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Zona', width: 140, align: 'left', sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Tienda', index: 'Tienda', width: 150, align: 'left', sortable: true },
                { name: 'StockInventariadoPesos', index: 'StockInventariadoPesos', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$ " } },
                { name: 'StockAbiertoPesos', index: 'StockAbiertoPesos', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$ " } },
                { name: 'StockAbiertoUnidades', index: 'StockAbiertoUnidades', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'integer', formatoptions: { thousandsSeparator: "." } },
                { name: 'PorcentajeAbiertos', index: 'PorcentajeAbiertos', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " %" } },
                { name: 'NoEncontradosPesos', index: 'NoEncontradosPesos', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$ " } },
                { name: 'NoEncontradosUnidades', index: 'NoEncontradosUnidades', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'integer', formatoptions: { thousandsSeparator: "." } },
                { name: 'PorcentajeNoEncontrados', index: 'PorcentajeNoEncontrados', width: 120, align: 'right', sortable: true, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: ".", decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " %" } }
            ],
            pager: "#pager-disponibles-zonas",
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,
            recordtext: "{2} registros",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            multiselect: false,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            rownumber: false,
            rowNum: -1,
            footerrow: true,
            userDataOnFooter: true,
            treeGrid: true,
            ExpandColumn: 'Tienda',
            grouping: false,
            groupingView: {
                groupField: ['Zona'],
                groupColumnShow: [false],
                groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Tienda(s)</b>'],
                groupCollapse: true
            },
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                $('#progreso').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
                if (status) {
                    var row = $(this).getRowData(rowid)
                    refreshGraph(row.Type, row.ID);
                }
            }
        });
```

This works but when I click a sortable column, the sorting icon changes accordingly (toggling from asc to desc and desc to asc), however, no Ajax call is made in order to actually sort the data.

What is missing here?

Comment: Provide a working example (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet) so it wil be possible to check.

Comment: That is not possible..... the AJAX call accesses a datastore locally in my PC. I have compared this setting to the settings in JQGrid demo and it is almost identical. What may be the problem? only the order indicator is shown when I click on the column header, but no AJAX call is performed.

Comment: Provide a working version with the ajax call (that doesn't work...), but everything else does.

Comment: What you plan to do is trial and error tests... which I can do by myself and what finally I did. The problem was finally caused by the treeGrid property. When it is enabled, sorting does not work. When it is disabled, sorting does work. The problem is that I need treeGrid. Maybe I will open another question with this concrete fact so someone that really knows jqGrid can help.

Comment: No matter what your question will be - without actually seeing the code/error/request - being able to debug the problem - it will be very hard to help. This is why I asked for a "working" example (even if the working is only partial...)